# How to map two lists using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, collections

If i have a List of dates like this :

```
List<DateTime>  {5-10-2014,6-10-2014,7-10-2014}
```

---

and i have list of sessions like this :

```
List<int>  {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

---

How to map the sessions to dates considering that each date has two sessions in order(using linq).

---

i want the result like that :

```
5-10-2014    1
5-10-2014    2
6-10-2014    3
6-10-2014    4
7-10-2014    5
7-10-2014    6
```

Comment: How the dates are associated with the session? Does the first date is associated with the first two items in your session list and the second date is associated with the next two items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it with [`GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin(v=vs.95).aspx):

```
var groupedDates = dates
    .Select((date, index) => new { Date = date, Index = index })
    .GroupJoin(
        numbers,
        dateWithIndex => dateWithIndex.Index,
        num => (num - 1) / 2,
        (dateWithIndex, nums) => new[] 
        { 
            new { Date = dateWithIndex.Date, Number = nums.First() },
            new { Date = dateWithIndex.Date, Number = nums.Last() }
        })
    .SelectMany(grp => grp);
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/2IIKhj

Here's how this works:

1. Project the dates list into a new sequence containing the index of each date and the date itself
2. `GroupJoin` that collection with the list of numbers. To correlate the two, use the `Index` we got from step 1 for the date, and `(num - 1) / 2`, since `Index` is zero-based.
3. To build the reusult, create a new array containing two items, one for each number associated with the date.
4. Finally, call `SelectMany` to flatten the sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple solution:

`dates` is a list of `DateTime` and sessions is a list of `int`.

```
var result = sessions.Select((session,i) => 
                      new{Session = session, Date = dates[i/2]});
```

The result contains an IEnumerable of [anonymous objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), you can access its properties like this:

```
foreach(var sessionDate in result)
{
   var date = sessionDate.Date;
   var session = sessionDate.Session.
}
```

Comment: Now how to access the date in `sessions` list , i mean after that query what 's the content of `sessions`

Comment: Try it before commenting.

Answer (score 2):

Assumed that listi.Length == 2*listd.Length

```
List<int> listi = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }.ToList();
List<DateTime> listd = new DateTime[] { DateTime.Parse("5-10-2014"), DateTime.Parse("6-10-2014"), DateTime.Parse("7-10-2014") }.ToList();

IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, int>> result = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, listi.Count)
    .Select(x => new Tuple<DateTime, int>(listd[x / 2], listi[x]));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you develop your project with .Net 4.0 or higher versions you can use Zip().

```
IEnumerable<int> keys = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; // your keys
IEnumerable<DateTime> values = new List<DateTime>() { DateTime.Parse("5 - 10 - 2014"), DateTime.Parse("6 - 10 - 2014"), DateTime.Parse("7 - 10 - 2014") }; // your values
var mappedDictionary = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new {
            k,
            v
        }).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
```

This link proves how it works..
https://dotnetfiddle.net/yKYf8S

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not going to get the results he wants

Comment: Let's give him a chance to give a shoot;)

Answer (score 1):

I think best way to map values in C# is to use `Dictionary<Key,Value>`. You can have a one-to-many relationship -- that is, one date has several sessions. The code would look like this:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<int>> dicDateSesstion = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<int>>();
```