# How to map an object consists of arrays into a list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have the following classes:

```cs
public class EquipmentListFilter
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public string Operand { get; set; }
    public string FilterType { get; set; }
}

public class EquipmentFilterPack
{
    public string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }
    public string[] keywords { get; set; }
    public string[] FilterTypes { get; set; }
    public string[] Operands { get; set; }
}
```

I get the `EquipmentFilterPack` object as input in my API. I have to map `EquipmentFilterPack` to a list of `EquipmentListFilter`. The final result should be `List<EquipmentListFilter>`.

For example:

```
[
    {
        ColumnName = "C1",
        Keyword = "kw1",
        Operand = "AND",
        FilterType = "ٍIS"
    },
    {
        ColumnName = "C2",
        Keyword = "kw2",
        Operand = "AND",
        FilterType = "ٍIS NOT"
    },
    ...
]
```

A similar thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425728/how-to-map-two-lists-using-linq).

How can I create the final list? Is there any LINQ solution?

Comment: Without LINQ, a simple way is that you can use `for` loop to get each element by index. Assume that those 4 properties' arrays have the **same length**. Are those 4 properties' arrays have the same length?

Comment: @YongShun Yes, They are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clarified that those four properties arrays have the exact same length, the easiest way is you can use a `for` loop to iterate and get the element by an index that has been covered in the comment.

Another approach will be performing CROSS JOIN via LINQ:

> Query expression

```cs
List<EquipmentListFilter> filters = (from a in pack.ColumnNames
                   from b in pack.keywords
                   from c in pack.FilterTypes
                   from d in pack.Operands
                   select new EquipmentListFilter
                    {
                        ColumnName = a,
                        Keyword = b,
                        FilterType = c,
                        Operand = d,
                    }).ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YrspcD)

Answer (score 0):

There are nuget packages that can help you like imapper and newtonsoft.

If you do it yourself, you would have to:

1. Build a for loop.
2. Get the biggest length from the array properties' of EquipmentFilterPack.
3. Use the 'Length' as the iteration count to iterate over the properties.
4. Guard yourself from indexoutofbound exception by not continuing iterating over arrays with smaller lengths than the current iterating index.
5. Create EquipmentListFilterList that will be outside the for loop, (List).
6. Create EquipmentListFilter object in every iteration and feed its properties from the EquipmentFilterPack properties.
7. Add every newly created EquipmentListFilter to EquipmentListFilterList.

A LINQ solution is also viable, although it would be more convoluted.